# ASP.NET: How to reduce chance of getting error 503

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, error-handling, web-config

I have an asp.net app hosted at a (for now, unnamed) hosting company. This app uses a small MS SQL database.

During the past couple of months, my complete website (whether it's the app page or plain static html page) was not accessible twice due to error 503. They just shut down the website without notifying me. However I monitor the website every few hours and called them when I found the problem. Then they restarted the application pool and everything worked again.

They told me that my website/app reached their "Worker Process Limit" of "100MB" and that's the reason for their shutting it down.

This seems to be the only hosting company that advertises their Worker Process Limit with their hosting plan so I don't have a basis of comparison with other companies's plans.

So, my questions are:

1.Could someone explain what the Worker Process Limit is in Windows server environment? And is 100MB considered small or adequate?

2.How can I handle or avoid reaching this limit within my app? Is this possible or is it just the number of visitors is too high? I average only a few hundred visitors a day.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, the WPL is based off of how much resources your application utilizes.  Naturally, this could be a result of how many users visits your web application (or more so, concurrently) but it extends a bit beyond that.

I believe what this is saying, is that **your application is memory hungry.**  Is that a bad thing?  No, but when you only have 100MB at your disposal it is.

I would say your first step would be to get that web application local and see the actual resource utilization.  I know this is a very open-ended answer, but you'll have to do the resource tuning to slim down your memory consumption.  There's a chance that this is just from a bug (say, an array of objects that are not getting disposed of properly).